# How to generate barcode using specific font in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, barcode, code39

I need to generate barcode image in format of code39. I need to use specific font 'w39H.fft' , 'w39LC.fft'

I am using this library to generate the bar-code image.

https://github.com/fobiaweb/Barcode39

```
include('Barcode39.php');
$bc = new Barcode39("This is test barcode srting *&*%$# :"); 
// set text size 
$bc->barcode_text_size = 5; 
// set barcode bar thickness (thick bars) 
$bc->barcode_bar_thick = 4; 
// set barcode bar thickness (thin bars) 
$bc->barcode_bar_thin = 2; 
// save barcode GIF file 
$bc->draw("barcode.gif");
```

But i could not find any option to use font. 
You can also suggest any other library.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: Please look at the guideline for better questioning https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rakesh You haven't reported back. Wasn't my answer of any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of what the *.fft file format is but the only code in the library that handles text makes use of [imagestring()](http://php.net/imagestring) to print the human-readable text below the barcode. These are the relevant bits:

```
/**
 * Barcode text size
 *
 * @var int $barcode_text_size
 */
public $barcode_text_size = 3;
$font_size = $this->barcode_text_size;
imagestring($img, $font_size, $pos_center, $this->barcode_height - $barcode_text_h - 2,
            $barcode_string, $_000);
```

As per the docs, you can use [imageloadfont()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) to feed it with custom fonts, but they seem to be custom platformt-dependent bitmap definitions. If that's not what you need, this it not the library you want.